# regex to split string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am planning to split a string in java using regex. My input will be as follows

2010-11-10 00:00:00,999, some string follows

I am using

```
inputString.split("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3},)");
```

This gives a string[] with two elements, second element is "some string follows" but first element is empty string, how to get the first part of the string.

**Update:** I cant assume the date will be at the beginning. Sorry for leaving it out earlier.

Comment: So what pieces are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting 2010-11-10 00:00:00,999, & some string follows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably don't want split. Split's argument is the delimited between the strings. So you are succesfully matching the timestamp, but split is returning you the string before that (empty) and after ("some string follows").

You probably want

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2},\\d{3},)")
            .matcher("2010-11-10 00:00:00,999, some string follows");
if (m.find()) {
    String first_part = m.group(1);
}
```

(untested!)

Comment: is there someway to get the delimiter also? <sorry prev question was for some other answer>

Comment: What do you mean by "delimiter" here?

Comment: I tried using Pattern earlier could not get it working..the above does not seem to work either.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not anywhere I can test right now. What doesn't work about what I posted, and what didn't work in what you tried? Split() is definitely not the right approach, though

Comment: @Paul: you either want to use `m.find()` (to match a substring of the input) or you need to surround your regex with `.*` to match the rest of the string.  The second comma should probably be *outside* of the matching group but I suppose that depends on what th OP wants to extract. Also semi-colon after the first line.

Comment: @Mark Peters, thanks, when I wrote the answer the that was the whole input, but the OP has clarified it might not be at the beginning.  The comma is inside in the OP's regexp. And added the ;. Edited.

Comment: it does not match anything m.matches() is false. I had same problem too. I was thinking of writing something generic so I can extract date whereever it is in the string, if split is not a good approach then I might have to rethink how to do this.

Comment: Pattern is the correct approach. Let's try and get that working for you

Comment: with this m.group(0) gets the date, but wondering how to make this generic. can I write a function that takes pattern and group number as input and returns date?

Comment: Yes, you can. If you want the bit after the date too, add a (.*) to the end of the regexp and that should be .group(2)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use a SimpleDateFormat for parsing the date part, which was designed for this task?

e.g.

```
DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS");
Date date = fmt.parse("2010-11-10 00:00:00,999");
```

To get this part of the input string you could find the second occurrence of a comma and return everything before it:

```
String input = "2010-11-10 00:00:00,999, yada yada";
String dateInput = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(',', input.indexOf(',') + 1));
```

Or the regex way (using a positive lookbehind assertion to make sure it's the second comma):

```
String dateInput = input.split("(?<=.*,.*),")[0];
```

Comment: That is true but I have to extract this part from the input string

Comment: yeah but I dont want to assume the date will be at the beginning.

Comment: @user444300: that's something that's useful to put into your question then.  Don't leave requirements out of the question.  From your description it seems very clear that the date will be at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Why not search for the second comma and break the string into two manually? Seems too complex to me to perform such a simple task. Of course, that would work assuming the format is always exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you are capturing the correct pieces. The regex `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2},\d{3},)` captures the ENTIRE date. If you add capturing groups around each piece, then you can loop through each captured group. As to the two groups, the way Java regexes work is that group 0 is the entire matched string, then the groups thereafter are the captured groups.

Comment: The problem is not the regexp. It's the use of split